# ESLint couldn't find the plugin "eslint-plugin-@typescript-eslint"

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, gatsby

I'm not sure if there's a bug with something I'm using or whether I've just set something up wrong here, but I'm getting this error from eslint when running `eslint src --fix` about "eslint-plugin-@typescript-eslint"

I've specified the plugin as listed in the @TypeScript-eslint docs but I'm getting this weird error where eslint is trying to add 'eslint-plugin-' to the start of the plugin name (the package name is `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin`)

I'm using Gatsby and the accompanying [TypeScript plugin](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-typescript/?=typescrip).

**Error**

```
$ eslint src --fix

Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 4.19.1.
ESLint couldn't find the plugin "eslint-plugin-@typescript-eslint". This can happen for a couple different reasons:

1. If ESLint is installed globally, then make sure eslint-plugin-@typescript-eslint is also installed globally. A globally-installed ESLint cannot find a locally-installed plugin.

2. If ESLint is installed locally, then it's likely that the plugin isn't installed correctly. Try reinstalling by running the following:

    npm i eslint-plugin-@typescript-eslint@latest --save-dev
```

---

**.eslintrc.js:**

```
module.exports = {
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true,
    es6: true,
    'jest/globals': true,
  },
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint', 'react', 'jest'],
  extends: [
    'standard',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:jest/recommended',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
    // 'eslint-config-prettier', // must be last
    'prettier/@typescript-eslint',
  ],
  rules: {
    'react/prop-types': 0,
    'jsx-quotes': ['error', 'prefer-single'],
    'react/no-unescaped-entities': 0,
  },
  settings: {
    react: {
      version: 'detect',
    },
    linkComponents: [
      // Components used as alternatives to <a> for linking, eg. <Link to={ url } />
      'Hyperlink',
      { name: 'Link', linkAttribute: 'to' },
    ],
  },
}
```

---

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "jmulholland.com",
  "description": "My personal website",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "gatsby develop",
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "lint": "eslint src --fix",
    "prettier": "prettier \"**/*.+(js|jsx|ts|tsx|json|css|md|mdx|graphql)\"",
    "format": "yarn prettier --write",
    "type-check": "tsc --noEmit",
    "validate": "yarn lint && yarn prettier --list-different"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "gatsby": "^2.1.4",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.0.6",
    "gatsby-plugin-styled-components": "^3.0.5",
    "gatsby-plugin-typescript": "^2.0.10",
    "gatsby-plugin-typography": "^2.2.7",
    "gatsby-remark-prismjs": "^3.2.4",
    "gatsby-source-contentful": "^2.0.29",
    "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^2.3.0",
    "prismjs": "^1.15.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.2",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.0",
    "react-typography": "^0.16.18",
    "styled-components": "^4.1.3",
    "typography": "^0.16.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^1.4.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^1.4.2",
    "babel-jest": "^24.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.0",
    "babel-preset-gatsby": "^0.1.8",
    "dotenv": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^22.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "husky": "^1.3.1",
    "jest": "^24.1.0",
    "lint-staged": "^8.1.5",
    "prettier": "^1.16.4",
    "typescript": "^3.3.3333"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to load plugin @typescript-eslint: Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-@typescript-eslint'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54514989/failed-to-load-plugin-typescript-eslint-cannot-find-module-eslint-plugin-typ)

Answer (score 21):

Solution was simply to upgrade to the latest version of eslint

Comment: I am facing exact problem. Where you using `eslint` globally?

Comment: I don't use eslint globally

Comment: I'm using the latest version and sadly its not fixing it.

Comment: i ran into the same issue. upgrading from `3.3.0` to `^8.36.0` resolved the issue—surprisingly

Answer (score 14):

Adding `"root": true` to the `.eslintrc.json` helped me.

> `"root": true` is a generally good ESLint practice to indicate this file is the root-level one used by the project and ESLint should not search beyond this directory for config files.

https://typescript-eslint.io/getting-started#details

Comment: What the "root" is, and why it may help you read - https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/configuration-files#cascading-and-hierarchy

Answer (score 6):

I just faced this issue on a large monorepo, found two solutions that fixed it for us:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint src --resolve-plugins-relative-to ."
  }
}
```

If you use yarn workspace, `yarn run` could also do the trick:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "yarn run eslint src"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For any future readers who might be facing this issue, in my case I was working with a multi-stage Docker build based on the `node:alpine` image. The multi-stage build was meant to create a separation between the app's `dependencies` and the `devDependencies` (in `package.json`).

At some point in creating my `Dockerfile`, which underwent quite a few modifications over several hours, I added the following line towards the beginning of my `Dockerfile`:

```
ENV NODE_ENV production
```

This causes `npm` to ignore the `devDependencies` packages, which in turn causes ESLint to fail (because it isn't installed).

I moved the environment variable declaration to my final (release) build stage, where I originally wanted it, and then `npm` installed all required packages and ESLint ran successfully.

Hopefully this saves someone some precious time.

Answer (score 1):

my solution on Mac was like

- go to global node_modules `cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/`
- delete global eslint `rm -rf eslint`
- run the command once again `eslint index.js app storybook test --fix --ext .js,.ts,.tsx`
- profit

Answer (score 1):

Issues can cause this:

- Outdated ESLint.
- ESLint installed globally and locally at the same time. [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65139393/8474284).
- Missing `.eslintrc` config file from the project folder. Solution: `npx eslint --init`
- Additional `node_modules` folder in the project-parent folder outside your project.
- Additional `.eslintrc` in the project-parent folder outside your project.
- Wrong package config. [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68218843/8474284).

Answer (score 0):

Another reason that could cause this issue is not having `ESLint` configured.

In my case, adding a `.eslintrc.json` file to the root directory (with proper configuration) fixed the issue.

Comment: Wouldn't his existing solution of using `.eslintrc.js` also work?

Comment: I don't see any reason why it wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Since i faced same issue with `eslint` now, i'm posting here about the root cause of the issue in my case.

I installed this `eslint-nullish-coalescing` plugin which is a fork of `eslint` to nullish coalescing. This plugin changed the content of `node_module\.bin\eslint.cmd` file.

from

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\..\eslint\bin\eslint.js" %*
) ELSE (
  @SETLOCAL
  @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node  "%~dp0\..\eslint\bin\eslint.js" %*
)
```

to

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\..\eslint-nullish-coalescing\bin\eslint.js" %*
) ELSE (
  @SETLOCAL
  @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node  "%~dp0\..\eslint-nullish-coalescing\bin\eslint.js" %*
)
```

Because of this, eslint could not find the right plugins for its work, hence the error .

Though OP is not using `eslint-nullish-coalescing` package, but i would suggest to verify the content of the `node_modules\.bin\eslint.cmd` file if anyone who are facing this issue now.

Answer (score 0):

In my case one of the parent directories had another node_modules folder.

Moving the package directory into a path with no other node_modules folder in the parent tree removed the error.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I met the same problem when I am trying to use ESLint and Prettier in my project which is created in 2017 and using Angular 9. After googled a lot, I just solved it by upgrading ESLint to version 8+. Version 6+ also works but version 7+ may cause another error. That's really weird.

Then I added a new script like:

```
./node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js ./ --ext .ts,.tsx --config .eslintrc.js --fix
```

And ESLint just works fine. And you can add some configs in `.eslintrc.js` (on) file to let ESLint know which files are supposed to be linted and formatted.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error as lint script in my code had below sections added.
'./src/**/*' './test/*'
After removing these from script, job started passing. Error is misleading though and took lots of time to fix.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).